# the Content of Drop down suggest list for AutoCompleteTextView does not show in android 2.3

Tags: android, android-support-library, autocompletetextview

I had UI-problem when I test my app on an `android 2.3` device , the Content of `Drop down` suggest list for `AutoCompleteTextView` does not show
[image]

**But** when I test my app on an `android 4.2` device , the Content of `Drop down` suggest list
works
[image]
I'am using android Support Library. and I'am using `Theme.AppCompat.Light` Theme for Application.

`loadData` method which i used to fill the Content of `Drop down` suggest list

```
private void loadData () {

    final int[] to = new int[]{android.R.id.text1};
    final String[] from = new String[]{"keyword"};
    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, null, from, to,SimpleCursorAdapter.FLAG_REGISTER_CONTENT_OBSERVER);
    adapter.setCursorToStringConverter(new SimpleCursorAdapter.CursorToStringConverter() {
        @Override
        public CharSequence convertToString(Cursor cursor) {
            final int colIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("keyword");
            return cursor.getString(colIndex);
        }
    });

    adapter.setFilterQueryProvider(new FilterQueryProvider() {
        @Override
        public Cursor runQuery(CharSequence keyword) {
            Cursor results= keywordSearch.searchKeywords(keyword.toString()); 
            return results;
        }
    });

    tbxSearch.setThreshold(2);
    tbxSearch.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had solve the UI-Problem by changing `layout` of `drop down` list.

**Change**:

```
SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, null, from, to,SimpleCursorAdapter.FLAG_REGISTER_CONTENT_OBSERVER);
```

**To**:

```
SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(MainActivity.this, R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item , null, from, to,SimpleCursorAdapter.FLAG_REGISTER_CONTENT_OBSERVER);
```